# Submit form does not work correctly

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <?php echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');?>
        <?php $u = 'placeholder="Username"';
              $p = 'placeholder="Password"';?>
        <?php echo form_input('username','',$u,'class="input-block-level"');?>
        <?php echo form_password('password','',$p,'class="input-block-level"');?>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit','Sign in','class= "btn btn-primary"');?>
        <?php echo anchor('login/signup','Sign up!', 'class= "btn btn-primary"');?>.<br/><br />
        <?php echo anchor('login/admin_log','Go to admin login page');?>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have a login form. When I click sign , it's not redirecting me to the form_open page.

Comment: Did you forget the `action` attribute of the `form` tag?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an action for the form, usually a php script on a different page to handle the data:

as an example:

```
          <form action= "../create_comment.php" method="post" name="comments_form" id="comment" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
              <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
              <input name="name" type="text" value=" ">
            </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms Parent and child(`form` inside `form`).
Submitting the form will process parent form. Simply remove the first (parent) `<form>` tag.

```
<form class="form-signin">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------ remove this
    ...
    ...
</form>
^^^^^^^ ------ and this
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using CodeIgniter?

You have 2 form tags in your code.

here: `<form class="form-signin">...</form>`

and here:
`<?php echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');?>...<?php echo form_close();?>`

Get rid of this one: `<form class="form-signin">...</form>`

Your second form tag will handle everything for you. The output will look something like this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/login/validate_credentials" />
```

If you need to add a class or any other property to the form tag, do this:

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');
echo form_open('email/send', $attributes);
```

[Form helper on CI Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)